# Redeploy a singleton with timer task

Tags: java, singleton

I have a web server application runing with JVM, where i manage the class loader.
My application have an singleton with a cycle timertask. During the redeployment i clean all the references to Class(es).
I look like that my singleton with the timerTask doen't die.
I add a finalize method with print. the finalize method was never call.
Any solution?

Comment: why not just allow the server to manage that?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Servlet lifecycle](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzatz/51/program/servlife.htm). Your servlet can implement `destroy()`, which will get called on unloading. Use that to switch off timers etc.

Note that you can *never* rely on `finalize()` being called.

Answer (score 0):

These things are much easier with Spring and Quartz. In Spring you can define a bean to be a [singleton](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-modes) (not exactly the same with the singleton design pattern, but it will serve your needs). Also Quartz is much more powerful/flexible/easy to work with than TimerTask.

Spring will take care redeployment issues for you. You just need to define a destroy method.